# filter specific rownames with spaces

Tags: r

My rownames consists of 6 strings that are separated by a space. I would like to keep the rows that has `0` in the third string. I am not sure how this is done, since the strings are not defines as columns.

```
hsa-miR-143-3p TGAGAAGAAGCACTGTAGCTCTT 6AT u-TT 0 0                           0                          1
hsa-miR-10a-5p GACCCTGTAGATCCGAATTTGTA 1GT u-A 0 u-G                          1                          0
hsa-miR-10a-5p GACCCTGTAGATCCGAATTTGTG 1GT 0 0 0                             54                         24
hsa-miR-1296-5p TTAGGGCCCTGGCTCCATCT 0 0 0 u-CC                              11                         17
hsa-miR-887-3p GTGAACGGGCGCCATCCCGAGGCTT 0 0 0 d-CTT                          1                          8
hsa-miR-10a-5p ACCCGGTAGATCCGAATTTGTG 5GT 0 d-T 0                             7                         11
```

out:

```
hsa-miR-1296-5p TTAGGGCCCTGGCTCCATCT 0 0 0 u-CC                              11                         17
hsa-miR-887-3p GTGAACGGGCGCCATCCCGAGGCTT 0 0 0 d-CTT                          1                          8
```

Comment: It would be better if you posted the `dput` of your data frame (e.g. `dput(df)`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `df` holds your data frame, you could try

```
idx <- which(read.table(text=rownames(df))$V3=="0")
df[idx, ]
```